# how to check starting/ending word in a long space delimited string

Tags: arrays, string, removing-whitespace

I have a string array i.e.

```
string[] input_Text = new string[] { "i am wanting to take admission in the univeristy of the islamabad", "we are enjoying all the talent here at the city of atlanta", "what are you doing there" };
```

and a stopWords array i.e.

```
string[] stopWords = new string[] { " are ", " am ", " all ", " at ", " here ", " i ", " in ", " of ", " take ", " the ", " there ", " to ", " what ", " we ", " you " };
```

I have to replace stopWords in input_Text with " " (whiteSpace) but issue is that i am having " i " in stopWords array and text contains 'i' at start mean there is no whitespace at start of 'i'. So issue is the starting and ending word strings in text doesn't match with the stopWords, so unable to remove those words. The loop I'm using is....

```
for (int i = 0; i < input_Text.Count(); i++) 
 { 
   for (int j = 0; j < stopWords.Count(); j++) 
   {
      input_Text[i] = input_Text[i].Replace(stopWords[j], " ");
   } 
  }
```

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: One way could be to split `input_Text` using `" "` as delimiter and run the test on each element (= each word). Your stop words list won't need leading and trailing whitespaces. At the end, recombine into 1 string with spaces in between each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your data, you can add a space character to the beginning and end of `input_Text` before `Replace`, and remove them afterwards:

```
string s = " " + input_Text[i] + " ";
s = s.Replace(stopWords[j], " ");
input_Text[i] = s.Substring(1, s.Length - 2);
```

Not very efficient, but should work fine.